# Apexcharts.js bar chart css issue

Tags: css, apexcharts

I need help with some CSS issues that I'm facing when trying to render my charts using Apexcharts library.

My first issue is that the data labels are going behind the scroll. I would like the `offsetX` to remain at something like 20px because I want the data labels next to the bar graph. As can be seen in the image below, the data label for `data_10` is going behind the scroll bar:

[image: data label for the last data point is cropped out]

It becomes more visible when the numbers get bigger.

My second concern is whether it's possible to make the height of the individual bars of the graph fixed and make the graph take 100% height. This is because if there is a lot of data, it's hard to read to the labels:

[image: too many data points make the graph hard to read]

In addition, if there is only one (or few) data point (s), it takes up all the space and you can't read the data labels.

[image: one or few data entries will crop out the data labels]

Therefore, is it possible to make every bar height of `50px` for example? The graph can take up all the space it needs because it is wrapped in a container that allows vertical scrolling.

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/763mkaze/2/

Answer (score 1):

Have an idea on how to solve this problem. Not a great solution, but it works. In the `height` propery I just calculate the length of my array and multiply for the height I want for each bar:

```
const options = {
    chart: {
        height: array.length * 20,
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Then, I wrapped my chart in a `div` with a fixed height and the scroll property set to auto:

```html
<div class="graphic-container">
    <!-- Your chart goes here -->
</div>
```

The `graphic-container` class only have this:

```
.graphic-container {
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```